# How to change the focusRect color in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, air, focusrect

If a MovieClip or Button gets selected with TAB, a yellow border is displayed around it. Is it possible to change the color of the [focusRect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#focusRect) in AS3 or AIR?
If not, what would be an alternative way to highlight a selected button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. But you can manage focus, and draw whatever you want, or change state of your UI component. It's a good practice for UI components create several states: normal, highlited, selected, disabled and manage them with disabled system focusRect.

```
myComponent.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);
myComponent.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, onFocusOut);
```